# erros al usar una ruta post laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

hola tengouna ruta de tipo post

Route::post('reporte/solicitides','...');

si un usuario usa la ruta aparece un mensaje de error **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**

[image: error MethodNotAllowedHttpException]

quisiera que en lugar de aparecer esa vista de error, me muestre un personalizada por mi. para no mostrar esa vista y el usuario entienda el error

[image: return view('errors.500');]
vista de destino return view('errors.500');

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor explicar mejor tu duda?

Comment: Hay una sección completa en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors) sobre manejo de errores. Te sugiero que le des una leída, pero lo primero sería configurar APP_DEBUG en `false` en el archivo `.env`  para entornos que no son de desarrollo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según entiendo quieres que cuando un usuario entre a una ruta que no exista te muestre una pantalla personalizada,

Puedes utilizar esta propiedad en tu rutas `fallback` , para que cuanto una ruta no exista o como tu muestras en ese ejemplo entre la ruta de fallback y muestre lo que tu desees.

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
Route::fallback('WebController@error404');
```

Entonces puedes mostrar la vista que desees y cuando intenten entrar en una ruta que no existe de la misma forma se mostrar la vista que hayas indicado.

Deja esa ruta afuera de cualquier middleware.

Comment: gracias me funciono bien